# Save list of objects to local database - Windows Phone 8

Tags: database, list, windows-phone

I would like to save my data from object to local database. If I add fields from my class it's simple:

```
[Table]
public Class XXX{
public string _id;


        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = false, DbType = "NVarChar(10) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("id");
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("id");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

But what I have to do if my class look like ?

```
public class XXX
{

 public List<MyClass> objects;

}
```